# What curve does this represent as t varies over [−1, 1]?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $x(t) = \frac{1-t^2}{1 + t^2}$  and  $y(t) = \frac{2t}{1+t^2}$

What curve does this represent as $t$ varies over $[−1, 1]$?

*My attempt:*  I suspect it represent parabola. I know that by trigonometry formula
 $\sin2A = \frac{2\tan A}{1+\tan^2 A} =\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$. But here I used the graph of $\sin2A$, it look parabola, and $\cos2A = \frac{1-\tan^2A}{1+\tan^2A} =\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$, similarly it also look like parabola.

If anybody help me ,,i would be very thankful,,

Comment: $x^2 + y^2 = 1$

Comment: $\sin^2 2A + \cos^2 2A = 1$

Comment: Parabolas are quadratic.

Comment: Thanks  keny Lau@ ok,,but i don"t know,,

Comment: You may be drawing the y parabola on paper with one hand, but with the other hand you are pulling the paper at a non-constant speed.

Comment: Other lego legoh's have been placed in question-ban. Are they your siblings or are you trying to work around the rules by creating more accounts to be able to ask more bad questions?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen But this question seems to be OK according to rules of this website. Do we have any problem if this user has created another account to ask a not-bad question?

Comment: @JaideepKhare That is an interesting question. An attempt to circumvent a ban is obviously against the rules. On the other hand it might be ok to allow a fresh start, for the official way of getting out of a question ban is a bit taxing (for a good reason). A problem is that in the present case this may be "a fresh start number three". You see the problem :-)

Comment: @James lego legoh ; see each of the followings: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1958573/is-it-possible-to-elementarily-parametrize-a-circle-without-using-trigonometric/1958581#1958581 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255615/parametric-equation-of-a-circle-using-a-line/255626#255626 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/509028/equation-of-a-circle-from-parametric-functions-of-sin-and-cos/509030#509030

Comment: Thanks a lots @Famke ,,god bless u